# How to show/hide one result for react's hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently learning how to use react, and I am stuck on practice problem where I need to toggle button to open and close detail of specific country. Issue I am having is that whenever I click the button, it turns the switch on for entire list, thus everything gets propagated. Following code is what I am referring to:

```
// NOTE: only relevant codes are given

const DisplayInfo = ({countries}) => {

    // for button toggle
    const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(false)

    ... irrelevant codes ...    

    else{ // # of countries are 1 < n < 10
            return(
                <div>
                    {countries.map( country => 
                    <div key={country.name}>
                        {country.name}
                        <button onClick={() => setShowAll(!showAll)}> show </button>
                        <div>
                            Test: is it on? {showAll ? 'yes' : 'no'}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )}

                </div>
            )
        }

... some more irrelevant codes...
}
```

Where the given argument `countries` has object containing name of filtered countries and its info (e.g. capital, language spoken, etc).

And following is there result output:

[image]

where pressing "show" button will turn **all** test result from yes -> no and vice versa rather than only choosing one of them to change.

Any help regarding to this issue is appreciated!

Comment: Use a separate data state structure (object, map, array, etc..) to store the show/hide status of each country, add a button to toggle single country with callback that references that entry (country id key, mapped index, etc..). Please update your question with what you've attempted. We can help from there.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far to solve your issue.

Comment: So far, I tried making dictionary-like array in JS using ```const sw = countries.map( c => ({ name: c.name, isOn: false}))``` 
and pass that value in hook upon creation. Only issue with this is that the hook ```showAll``` becomes empty whenever I pass the above mapped array in following manner ```useState(sw)```.

While I was able to recognize which country is which upon clicking via 
```onClick={() => toggleSwitch(country)}``` (i.e. passing ```country``` as value), above issue prevents me from searching through object containing on-status... thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Could you paste the code you tried in the question so we can look at it?